# iPhoneX UI layout issue

Tags: ios, layout, iphone-x

I'm running my application in iPhoneX all layout is looking as require  but it will be leaving top and bottom margin.below is the screenshot.please anyone help me[image]

Comment: Have you used safe area layout guide?

Comment: For the iPhone X, try using a launch screen storyboard instead of launch images.

Comment: Thanks @karthikeyan

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati what fixed your issue post it as a answer so it will be helpful for others

Comment: use launch screen storyboard instead of launch images.

Answer (score 0):

Use Launch Storyboard instead of launch image will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this :

I have **multiple targets/schemes** in my project. So I had to use launch images instead of Launch Storyboard and therefore, I added one more launch image in Assests collection of size `1125x2436` for iPhoneX to make it working.

Hope this helps in such cases.